# Variable in SOSL Query

Tags: sosl, dynamic-sosl

In SOSL can I add a variable to the fields? As:

```
FIND {Clinica} IN Name Fields RETURNING Account(VARIABLE HERE)
```

Thanks

Comment: You would need **[`Dynamic SOSL`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_sosl.htm)**.

Comment: @AdrianLarson this link you sent doesn't show how to make dynamic "fields" clause

Comment: You only have to read between the lines a tiny bit to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic SOSL is what you need.

```
List<String> fields = new List<String> { 'Name' };
String term = 'FIND \'Clinica\' IN Name Fields RETURNING Account (' + String.join(fields, ',') + ')';
```

Comment: Thanks, Adrian! if i need more than 1 field do i separate with comma?

Comment: Yes, multiple elements would look like: `new List<String> { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'etc.' };`.

Comment: Thank you so much!